# Solution for large scale site maps

Tags: sitemap

I'm working on a nationwide retail web site with thousands of categories and product pages and my client wants to move from a single sitemap to multiple sitemaps based on page categorization. Here is how the new XML sitemaps for URLs would be constructed:

```
XML Sitemap for Category Pages – all category pages can fall into a single sitemap
XML Sitemap for Family Pages – if family pages are < 40,000 they can fall into a single sitemap
XML Sitemap for Product Pages – when product pages reach 40,000 a new XML sitemap would be created.
```

. Is there a free/professional solution for generating sitemaps based on such rules? Thanks

Comment: Nothing will come out of the box and do exactly what you need, but you can easily generate xml sitemaps with PHP using your item database. If you'd like I can post a small php script I use to generate a sitemap on a large site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a large site that I generate a sitemap with (well actually several sitemaps in batches of 40k URLs at a time). Here is a basic version of a php sitemap generator I wrote:

```
<?php

/* Do some stuff */
/* Connect to mysql etc */

/* create a dom document with encoding utf8 */
    $domtree = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

/* create the root element of the xml tree */
    $xmlRoot = $domtree->createElement("urlset");
    $xmlRoot -> appendChild(new DomAttr('xmlns', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'));
    $xmlRoot -> appendChild(new DomAttr('xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'));
    $xmlRoot -> appendChild(new DomAttr('xsi:schemaLocation', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd'));

/* append it to the document created */
    $xmlRoot = $domtree->appendChild($xmlRoot);

/* Loop through our database results and create URL entries for each page */
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $currentTrack = $domtree->createElement("url");
        $currentTrack = $xmlRoot->appendChild($currentTrack);
        $currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('loc','https://mysite.com/viewer.php?file='.$row['filename']));
        $currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('changefreq','weekly'));
        $currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('priority','1.0'));
    }

/* save the xml sitemap */
    $domtree->formatOutput = true;
    $domtree->preserveWhitespace = false;
    $domtree->save('sitemap.xml');
```

Obviously your milage will vary and you will need to do some things to make this work for you, but you could run a loop like this to generate a sitemap of all the categories, then all the products etc.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for...thanks for the sample code.